# single page apps using a view as user control in parent views

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, single-page-application

Please help me with this issue. I'm using durandal 2.0, requirejs, knockout and breeze for my spa application. I have a view(options.html) that i want to use as a user control for 3 other views(view1.html,view2.html, and view3.html). Below is the content of the options view.

```
define(['durandal/app', 'services/logger', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'services/unitofwork'], function (app, logger, ko, $, unitofwork) {

    var uow = unitofwork.create();
    var substatus = ko.observableArray();
    var vm = {
        status: substatus,
        activate: activate,
        startDate: ko.observable(),
        endDate: ko.observable(),
        attached: function (view, parent) {

            var startdatepicker = $(view).find('#startdatediv').datepicker();
            var enddatepicker = $(view).find('#enddatediv').datepicker();
            var starttxt = $(view).find('#txtstartDate');
            var endtxt = $(view).find('#txtendDate');

            startdatepicker.on('changeDate', function (ev) {

                starttxt.text(startdatepicker.datepicker('getAsText'));
                if ((date && date.valueOf()) > (endDate && endDate.valueOf())) {
                    $('#alert').show().find('strong').text('The start date cannot be after the end date');
                } else {
                    $('#alert').hide();
                    startDate = date;
                }

                startdatepicker.datepicker('hide');
            });
            enddatepicker.on('changeDate', function (ev) {

                starttxt.text(startdatepicker.datepicker('getAsText'));
                if ((date && date.valueOf()) > (endDate && endDate.valueOf())) {
                    $('#alert').show().find('strong').text('The start date cannot be after the end date');
                } else {
                    $('#alert').hide();
                    startDate = date;
                }

                enddatepicker.datepicker('hide');
            });
            console.log(startdatepicker.html());
            console.log(enddatepicker.html());
        }
    };

    return vm;

    function activate() {
        return true;
    }


    function fail(error) {

        logger.logError(msg, error, "", true);
    }
    function getPredicate() {
        var predicate = new breeze.Predicate.create("LookupId", "==", 1);
        console.log(predicate);


        return predicate;
    }
});
```

My problem now is when i try to navigate between the 3 parent views. It seems that the value i selected from the datepicker in the first parent view is recognized in the two other views. How do i achieve the logic where in the options view acts like it has a different id when navigated from the 3 different parent views. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to communicate between viewmodels (parent vm to options vm and vice versa) There are couple of ways

1. Messaging between VMs- you can use knockout notify or durandal messaging framework to sent messages between VMs, so the options vm refreshes its value, however it would be bit complex to remember the values for each vm, so the parent vms themselves should hold the values. That makes to lean toward my second option.
2. Instead of making options vm as a vm , just use it as class inside all the parent vms. In the parent views add the options view as template and bind the options object to it, this way you will have a options object per view and they are independent and will maintain their values themselves.

Comment: Thanks dhana, I was able to create a template for option vm and use it on the three views..

Comment: great, if you this is the answer you were looking for, could you accept the answer?